# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied - parsing json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, permissions

i'm trying to built a parser for a serveral json files but i have an issue declaring the `json_dict` this same code was working in python 2.7 but now i have 3.7 and i can't figure how to modify the code to avoid the `[Errno 13] Permission denied`

```
import os
import csv
import json
import sys
from importlib import reload

reload(sys)

file_path = 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop'
dirs = os.listdir(file_path)
file_out = 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/csv/json-to-csv.csv'
f = csv.writer(open(file_out, "w+"))
f.writerow(['file', 'id'])
for file in dirs:
    json_dict = json.loads(open(os.path.join(file_path, file)).read())
    print(file)
    for key in json_dict:
        for key1 in key:
            idi = key['id']

f.writerow([file[0:14], idi])
```

**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop\\csv'**

Comment: Windows Folder slashes tend to go the other way round. What happens if you change all the slashes in your file strings from (for example) `C:/Users/admin/Desktop/csv/json-to-csv.csv` to `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\csv\json-to-csv.csv`? Does it make a difference?

Comment: the only change is ***PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\csv***'

Comment: Does the `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\csv` folder actually exist? Are you running with administrator permissions?

Comment: yes, i had tried to change the folder path and now is working.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.